# How do I fix dynamic library's issue?

Tags: php, symfony, dynamic-library

everytime I use the composer to generate the database or to create a new symfony project, this warning shows up ,

```
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_apcu.dll' - n'est pas une application Win32
> valide.  in Unknown on line 0
```

I've already downloaded the .dll, put it in the ext folder and modified my php.ini and added the extension to the list :

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

extension=php_apcu.dll
```

but when I use the composer the warning keep showing up !!

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Can you re-word your post with more information otherwise it might get closed? What are you running or doing when you get this message? Please update your post by clicking `edit` and entering the details.

Comment: It's done now !

Comment: Can you run `php -i |grep 'PHP Version' from the command line? I want to know if you are trying to use PHP 7?

Comment: phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.1.1

Comment: I suspect your dll version of `php_apcu.dll` is of different architecture . First thing is to check your OS architecture and then download relevant dll

Comment: check here http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php `Which extension to download?`

Comment: Thank you so much @sakhunzai ! I downloaded the wrong one at first .

Comment: you are welcome @OmisBrown